# Root Galaxy S3 SGH-i747M (Andr. 4.4.2) without computer?

Tags: rooting, 4.4-kitkat

I've tried several different methods to root my Samsung Galaxy S3 (SGH-i747M) that I got in Canada from Fido about a year and a half ago, and I've had no success whatsoever.
I'm on Android 4.4.2, Baseband I747MVLUFNF2, Build# KOT49H, Kernel v.3.4.0-1784548, and my USB port is broken for the second time. My contract is nearly up, but I'd really like to get this thing rooted.

Methods already attempted:

```
Towelroot (+Modstrings)
Framaroot (All available options)
TowelPieRoot
Key Root Master
vRoot
Poot
MotoChopper Terminal Exploit
```

Anyone have more suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

calm down dude :)
[use this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1963790) ,or
 [download from chain fire](http://download.chainfire.eu/269/CF-Root/CF-Auto-Root/CF-Auto-Root-d2can-d2vl-sghi747m.zip)

> checksum: 3477ce82bac9930198c562f769c95774

then add to pda on odin then flash.
this is good method with computer, and without computer i think it doesnt work.
goodluck.